# use variable value in command python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

how can I use for to run this commands?

```
self.BTN0.hide()
self.BTN1.hide()
self.BTN2.hide()
self.BTN3.hide()
self.BTN4.hide()
self.BTN5.hide()
self.BTN6.hide()
self.BTN7.hide()
self.BTN8.hide()
self.label.hide()
self.resetBTN.hide()
```

I cant use this:

```
layoutList = ['BTN0','BTN1','BTN2','BTN3','BTN4','BTN5','BTN6','BTN7','BTN8','label','resetBTN']
for item in layoutList:
    self.item.hide()
```

how can I use variable value in command in python?

Comment: You created a list of string, so what you're actually trying to run is:
`self.'BTN0'.hide` which makes no sense. 
Try creating a list of objects, i.e without the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the objects directly in the lsit

```py
layoutList = [self.BTN0,self.BTN1,self.BTN2]
for item in layoutList:
    item.hide()
```

Comment: I have class and cant to remove self.